# iPhone, trying to subclass UIButton and the meeds all crashed when you call them

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to sub class the uibutton class and add some extra metheds to it.

If I ceate a class as follows

```
cTest *mTest=[cTest buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

and call any methed, one i created or allready there, example `[cTest setTitle:@"test" forState: UIControlStateNormal];` crashes.

my cTest class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface cTest : UIButton { 
    int i;
}

-(void) aTest;

@end
```

code to test the class:

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// this works fine
    UIButton *mBut=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [mBut setTitle:@"test" forState: UIControlStateNormal];   


// this does NOT  
    cTest *mTest=[cTest buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [cTest setTitle:@"test" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [mTest aTest]; // crashes here does not call my function
}
```

Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIButton buttonWithType: simply returns a UIButton* object, not a cTest* object.

You wil have to provide a class method (factory method) 
+ (cTest*) cTestWithType:

That one does not call [super buttonWithType:...] neither. 
Instead of that you will have to create a new cTest object with alloc  (and retain or autorelease, what ever serves your purpose best) and initialize it by setting the buttonType property.

... or just do the same without providing a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

`+buttonWithType:` is not guaranteed to return an instance of the class it's called on.  If you specify `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`, a private subclass of `UIButton` will be returned: `UIRoundedRectButton`.

To get an instance of your subclass, either override `+buttonWithType:`, or call a different initializer, like `-initWithFrame:`, or `-init`.

Answer (score 0):

It you want to add method to the UIButton, then the Objective-C: Categories may help.

```
@interface UIButton (Extend)
    -(void) aTest;
@end
```

Reference at: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html